# unixODBC/Oracle: How do I specify all the datasource info in the connection string ONLY, and not in the odbc*.ini files

Tags: oracle, unixodbc

I want to connect to Oracle (11g) using `unixODBC`.  I want the connection string ONLY to specify all the database/data-source information, and the ODBC INI files (`/etc/odbc.ini` and `/etc/odbcinst.ini`) to contain only generic driver info like where to find the '.so' etc. i.e. I want them to be static.  I want to do this so that I can get the connection string from the user externally, and connect to the datasource without having to modify any of the INI files or anything other on-disk configuration.

All the examples I saw make me define the server information in `/etc/odbc.ini` like this:

```
[myDSNname]
Driver = OracleODBC-11g
DSN = OracleODBC-11g
ServerName = //xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1521/SID_NAME
UserID = my_user
Password = my_pass
```

Now, I figured out how to get the UserID and Password out into the connection string by adding `"UID=my_user;PWD=my_pass"` to the connection string, and I removed them from `odbc.ini`.  My joy quickly passed when I couldn't find the way to get `ServerName` out of `odbc.ini` and into the connection string as well.  So how do I do this?  And is there a way to get rid of the DSN in `odbc.ini` altogether, and have just the `Driver` from `odbcinst.ini` in the connection string, like we are doing for MySQL?

**Edit:**
Trying any of the connection strings from [www.connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com) that don't seem to require TNS or a DSN, incliuding `EZCONNECT` variants, all give me:

```
[HY000] [unixODBC][Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified
    (12162) (SQLDriverConnectW)
```

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle#p17

Comment: @Brian - nope, I can't get any of those to work.  I always get: `[HY000] [unixODBC][Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified`

Comment: Don't use a tns names variant and/or make sure you have an entry in your tns names file.

Comment: @Brian: I am sure it was obvious but I'm not an expert in oracle or TNS or any of this stuff.  I assume you mean the variants that have a bajillion parentheses in them, which seemed to me to be the ones that don't rely on some other TNS or other configuration file to contain the actual server name/IP etc?  I tried those (using `Data Source` or `Server` or `CONNECTSTRING` in the connection string) to no avail.  I always get the error I pasted above...  is there any way to debug the connection strings and see what the driver is doing with it?  Or list all the directives it understands?

Comment: @Brian -and I was hoping the "Easy connect" variants would work too but they also give me the same thing.  Could that be due to a problem on the server (I need to enable EZCONNECT maybe?) or would I get a different error, and not one that doesn't look so much like a client-side problem... ?

Comment: Are you able to install an Oracle client?  There is a small download from Oracle called "instant client".  Or do already have an oracle client installed?  If yes there is a folder within the oracle home named 'network' that has the tnsnames.ora text file.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12736/discussion-between-e-dan-and-brian)

Answer (score 7):

just use Dbq=address:1521/orcl ,and you will get what you want